# Removal of nested key value in JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have some JSON data:

```
{
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":"value2",
       "HTTP Method": "POST",
       "key3":{
          "key3_1":"value3_1",
          "key3_2":"value3_2",
          "key3_3":"value3_3",
          "key3_4":"value3_4",
          "key3_5":"value3_5",
          "key3_6":"value3_6",
          "key3_7":"value3_7"
       },
       "key4":{
          "Accept":[
             "*/*"
          ]
       }
}
```

I want to do two operations here:

1. Removal of some nested key value pairs.
2. In the nested values, I need to change some like `"value3_5"` to `"val****"`.

In the second case, I can use this logic : If `s` is your string and `n` the number of not hidden characters: `s[:n] + '*' * (len(s)-n)`.

All I want to do is:

```
{

       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":"value2",
       "httpMethod":"POST",
       "key3":{
          "key3_1":"value3_1",
          "key3_2":"val*****",
          "key3_5":"value3_5",
          "key3_7":"val*****"
       },
       "key4":{
          "Accept":[
             "*/*"
          ]
       }
    }
```

I have removed here some nested key value pair and change the nested value to `"value3_2"` to `"val*****"` (the 2nd part was already done.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two functions to do these operations. First one takes `key/nested_key` name and delete it from data, while the second one takes `key/suffix` and replace it with stars:

```
data = {
       "key1":"value1",
       "key2":"value2",
       "HTTP Method": "POST",
       "key3":{
          "key3_1":"value3_1",
          "key3_2":"value3_2",
          "key3_3":"value3_3",
          "key3_4":"value3_4",
          "key3_5":"value3_5",
          "key3_6":"value3_6",
          "key3_7":"value3_7"
       },
       "key4":{
          "Accept":[
             "*/*"
          ]
       }
    }


def remove_nested_key_pair(key_name, nested_key_name):
    global data
    # Remove by key_name and nested_key_name
    data[key_name].pop(nested_key_name, None)

    return data


def replace_by_suffix(key_name, suffix):
    global data
    for i, v in data[key_name].items():
        # check whether suffix is at the end of any value
        # if yes replace it with 'val*****'
        if suffix == v[len(v) - 3:]:
            data[key_name][i] = 'val*****'

    return data
```

So when you call above functions like this:

```
data = remove_nested_key_pair('key3', 'key3_3')
data = remove_nested_key_pair('key3', 'key3_4')
data = remove_nested_key_pair('key3', 'key3_6')

data = replace_by_suffix('key3', '3_2')
data = replace_by_suffix('key3', '3_7')
```

The result will look like below:

```
{
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'HTTP Method': 'POST',
    'key3': {
        'key3_1': 'value3_1',
        'key3_2': 'val*****',
        'key3_5': 'value3_5',
        'key3_7': 'val*****'},
    'key4': {'Accept': ['*/*']}
}
```